# Break Out File Download into Background Process Using Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, download, resque, worker

I'm trying to break out file download into a background process. My assets are stored on S3.

My original (blocking) code looks like this

```
# From DownloadsController#download

data = open(path)
send_data(data.read, type: @download.mime_type, filename: @download.file_title)
```

So I've set up Redis and Sidekiq, and Created a `FielDownloadWorker`:

```
class FileDownloadWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(path, mime_type, file_title)
    data = open(path)
    # What happens next?
  end

end
```

Which is called using:

FileDownloadWorker.perform_async(path, @download.mime_type, @download.file_title)

**How do I initiate download from the worker?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up initiating the file download directly from S3 using [Query String Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_QSAuth.html). This way the file is downloaded directly to the client from S3 and the Rails app's thread isn't blocked.

Great writeup [here](http://www.tsunamibass.com/article/2013/05/force-file-download-amazon-s3-ruby-rails).

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You want the user to receive the file, right? It has to happen within the controller so that the controller can **respond** with the download. If you're trying to achieve concurrency try using threads:

```
@data = nil
t = Thread.new { @data = open(path) }
# ... do other stuff ...
t.join # wait for download to finish in other thread
send_data(@data.read, type: @download.mime_type, filename: @download.file_title)
```

If you decide to go with the worker approach you can have it update a database field or cache when the download is finished, then the user would have to make another request to your app to get the finished file. Something like:

1. User clicks button to initiate download.
2. Page updates with message "Your file is downloading, refresh the page in a few seconds"
3. User refreshes the page, your controller sees that the file is downloaded and does `send_data`

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is what I'm trying to do a non-standard approach?   Should I worry about blocking with a download?

Comment: It's pretty standard to defer blocking IO operations to a worker. But not standard to have the worker respond to the user with a download. Workers can't issue responses. Only controllers do. Some ways around that is with the aforementioned solutions.